# UITapGestureRecognizer sender is the gesture, not the ui object

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I've got a button called and I gave it a `UIGestureRecognizer` so that an `IBAction` is only run when the button is long pressed. You do this by adding a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the button iteself. Then you control drag that gesture recognizer to a function like this:

```
 @IBAction func handleGesture(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
    {
        let labelTap1=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "labelTapped:")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "**I want this to be the title of the button**", message:
            "This is the description of the function you pressed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

As you can see the `UIAlertController` appears, I want the title to show the buttons current title. If the sender of this function was the button, I could call this with `sender.currentTitle`. How can I get the title of the button that is tied to the gesture, when the sender of the function is the gesture.

I have seen posts like this in objective C, but nothing really on Swift. This is all for a project to get a buttons description when you longpress on the button itself.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get a reference to the view the gesture is added to via its view property.  In this case you are adding it to the button so the view property would return you you the button.

```
let button = sender.view as? UIButton
```

Comment: Yeah, the thing actually talking to you is the gesture recogniser; it's the agent that spots the action. You then need to ask it which view it was watching. Not sure if that helps any.